# Docker Swarm Init Fails: Address already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been going through the docker tutorial at https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/get-started/part3/#take-down-the-app-and-the-swarm and am up to the part where we're setting up our initial docker swarm.

I had this working at first, but then had to reconcile differences between a `snap install docker` and `apt install docker` on my system. Following this, when I try to run `docker swarm init` I'm told:

```
Error response from daemon: manager stopped: failed to listen on remote API address: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:2377: bind: address already in use
```

I have no other docker images or services running, so I'm fine killing or deleting anything, but I can't seem to figure out how to clear up this port so that I can initialize a new swarm.

Is there a way to either A) Kill the running swarm, or B) List the available swarms so that I can join it and then kill it from there as a swarm master?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you have installed docker from both snap/apt and you must uninstall one of the two (one is running in swarm mode and the docker client is connecting to the one that isn't).

To find the process running swarm use the following:

```
sudo ss --tcp --listening --processes --numeric | grep ":2377"
```

This will list the processes listening on the port 2377, on my case i find:

```
LISTEN   0      128     *:2377     *:*    users:(("dockerd",pid=1229,fd=24))
```

Now using the pid you can find the process location:

```
sudo readlink -f /proc/1229/exe
```

If the process comes from a `snap` then you know that you must stop it and remove the snap so it only leaves the inastallation from apt-get (or viseversa if you want to keep the snap installation).

Comment: Thanks for that guidance! being able to hunt down the process listening on the port was really useful. In my case, it was coming from the apt install which I had already purged, but doing so left orphaned processes. I fixed this by following some tutorials online on how to totally purge docker from my system, running kill -9 {{ process ID }} and then installing from snap. With that, docker is working like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, I had to restart docker:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

And then it started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the snap package with `sudo snap remove docker` I got the error `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.`
After trouble shooting, the solution was to uninstall, reinstall the apt docker packages and then restart the docker service with `systemctl restart docker` I confirmed it worked with `journalctl -xe` and `sudo docker run hello-world`